# "userIDs.push is not a function" when trying to push a new variable to an array

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having high difficulity understanding what am I doing wrong. I am coming from Android world where everything is so much simplier...anyway, I have a function that checks if the firebase database table I want to update exist, if not it creates one. So far so good, the issue is that after creating the table I want to update it's content afterwards and I am having issues understanding why I can't update the array I created.

here is my code -

[image]

as I sayed, I am having problems to push to my array. At firebase console log I get the following error -

[image]

As far as I know, arrays have the '.push' method. So what is it that I am doing wrong?

edit -

Here is how my database looks like. Obviously, I am holding 2 variables and not a variable and a list as I would like to. I want userUIDs to be a list -

[image]

edit -

here is my code -

```
function createOrUpdateDeletedVideosTable(profileUid, response) {

    const deletedVideosRef = database.ref(config.ENTITY_NAME_DELETED_VIDEOS);
    return deletedVideosRef.once("value").then(deletedVideosSnapshot => {
        var snapshotValue = JSON.stringify(deletedVideosSnapshot);
        console.log("snapshot value is null - " +  snapshotValue !== "null")
        console.log("snapshot value is null - " +  snapshotValue !== null)
        if (snapshotValue !== "null") {
            console.log("deleted videos ref exists - " + JSON.stringify(deletedVideosSnapshot));
            var deletedVideosVar = deletedVideosSnapshot.val();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(deletedVideosVar))
            deletedVideosVar["totalVideosDeleted"] = deletedVideosVar.totalVideosDeleted += 1
            deletedVideosVar.userUIDs.push(profileUid);
            deletedVideosRef.set(deletedVideosVar);
            return response.status(200).send('{"result": "OK"}');
        } 
        console.log("deleted videos ref does not exist")
        return createDeletedVideosTable(profileUid, response);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(500).send(`deleted video counter error - ${err}`);
    });
 }

 function createDeletedVideosTable(profileId, response) {
    var deletedVideosVar = {
        totalVideosDeleted : 1,
        userUIDs : {
            profileId
        }
    };
    // deletedVideosVar.totalVideosDeleted  = 1
    // deletedVideosVar.userUIDs.push(profileId);
    database.ref(config.ENTITY_NAME_DELETED_VIDEOS).set(deletedVideosVar);
    return response.status(200).send('{"result": "OK"}');
 }
```

Comment: Note that the line where you do xxxxx = yyyyyy += 1 is most probably not returning the expecting result

Comment: Could you please give me a code sample/fix for it to work the way I want it? I need to increment the number by 1 for eternity each time the functionm gets called and add the UID to the (wanna be) list called 'userUIDs'

Comment: Can you add your code as text to your question. For the moment it is an image and it is not easy to copy it.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec done

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec saw your answer. Thank you, though there is one issue that I am missing - where is the totalVideos counter?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I will upvote as soon as I get it corrent, for now this seems too robust to my issue and I can't understand how it fits my exact needs. I just need to change the lines in the code that create the "array" to an actual array and make the lines in the code that push to that array syntctily right and I am having a real trouble with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably because `deletedVideosVar["usersUIDs"]` is not an array.

By doing `deletedVideosVar["usersUIDs"]` you are accessing the `usersUIDs` property of the `deletedVideosVar` object, using the square brackets notation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

As explained in the Realtime Database [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val), "depending on the data in a `DataSnapshot`, the `val()` method may return a scalar type (string, number, or boolean), an array, or an object".

If you share the structure of your database we might confirm the assumption that `deletedVideosVar["usersUIDs"]` is not an array.

---

**UPDATE following your comment:**

The following code will update a Realtime Database node that is an array with new values. Note that, with the Realtime Database, you need to first read the existing array, then push a value and re-write the entire array.

```
  var db = firebase.database();
  var myRef = db.ref('myRef');

  myRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    //Let's create a random value for this example
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 1);

    if (snapshot.exists()) {

      var newArray = snapshot.val().array;
      newArray.push('A' + random);

      var postData = {
        array: newArray
      };

      var updates = {};
      updates['myRef'] = postData;
      db.ref().update(updates);
    } else {
      var postData = {
        array: ['A' + random]
      };

      myRef.set(postData);
    }
  });
```

---

For the increment of `deletedVideosVar.totalVideosDeleted`, you should probably use a transaction, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: I just looked at my database and you are right, it does not appear as an array. How can I fix it at the bottom function in order to make it an array?

Comment: Without seeing the exact format of `deletedVideosSnapshot` it is difficult to help you. But you could, for example, create your own object/array from `deletedVideosSnapshot.val()`. Also, it is not clear why you use `push()`. Are you sure you need an array? It seems you only push one element, so you could use a simple variable.

Comment: I have updated the post with a picture of my database. 
I am sure I need an array because I am summing the amount of UIDS that have deleted a video so one object containing all UIDS that have deleted and the other one just increment itself to eternity.

Comment: update - I got the solution I needed. I used parts of your code in order to get the answer I needed. please see my new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after seeing Renaud's answer I have composed my answer out of his answer because it was not exactly what I needed. So I changed my 'createDeletedVideosTable' method to the following code -

```
function createDeletedVideosTable(profileId, response) {
    console.log("No video deletion table available, creating a new one");
    const deletedVideosVar = {};
    deletedVideosVar['totalVideosDeleted'] = 1;
    deletedVideosVar['userIDs'] = [profileId];

    database.ref(config.ENTITY_NAME_DELETED_VIDEOS).set(deletedVideosVar);
    re
```

and then changed my `createOrUpdateDeletedVideosTable` method to the following -

```
function createOrUpdateDeletedVideosTable(profileUid, response) {

    const deletedVideosRef = database.ref(config.ENTITY_NAME_DELETED_VIDEOS);
    return deletedVideosRef.once("value").then(deletedVideosSnapshot => {
        const snapshotValue = JSON.stringify(deletedVideosSnapshot);
        if (snapshotValue !== "null") {
            const deletedVideosVar = deletedVideosSnapshot.val();
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Deleted videos table before deletion -  " + deletedVideosVar))
            deletedVideosVar.totalVideosDeleted += 1;
            deletedVideosVar.userIDs.push(profileUid);
            deletedVideosRef.set(deletedVideosVar);
            console.log("Successfully added a video to deleted videos table")
            return response.status(200).send('{"result": "OK"}');
        } 
        return createDeletedVideosTable(profileUid, response);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(500).send(`deleted video counter error - ${err}`);
    });
 }
```

works as needed - creates a table with 2 objects, one int that self increments for eternity each time the function is being called and the second one is an array that adds the profileUID to the array each time the function is being called.